# How to parse array of json objects to custom XML (node.js)

Tags: json, xml, transform

I'm trying to use js2xmlparser (node.js) to transform an array of JSON objects into a custom XML file.

The source array looks like this:

```
[
 {
   "ID": "3233705000002165882",
   "Quarter": "2020Q3",
   "Pkg_Total": "0.00",
   "Course_Each": "0.00"
 },
 {
   "ID": "3233705000002165883",
   "Quarter": "2020Q4",
   "Pkg_Total": "2.50",
   "Course_Each": "0.70"
 },
 {
   "ID": "3233705000002165884",
   "Quarter": "2021Q1",
   "Pkg_Total": "34.00",
   "Course_Each": "15.00"
 }
]
```

I need the target XML to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <records>
        <record id="3233705000002165882">
            <column name="Quarter">
                <value><![CDATA[2020Q3]]></value>
            </column>
            <column name="Pkg_Total">
                <value><![CDATA[$ 0.00]]></value>
            </column>
            <column name="Course_Each">
                <value><![CDATA[$ 0.00]]></value>
            </column>
        </<record>
        <record id="3233705000002165883">
            <column name="Quarter">
                <value><![CDATA[2020Q4]]></value>
            </column>
            <column name="Pkg_Total">
                <value><![CDATA[$ 2.50]]></value>
            </column>
            <column name="Course_Each">
                <value><![CDATA[$ 0.70]]></value>
            </column>
        </<record>
        <record id="3233705000002165884">
            <column name="Quarter">
                <value><![CDATA[2021Q1]]></value>
            </column>
            <column name="Pkg_Total">
                <value><![CDATA[$ 34.00]]></value>
            </column>
            <column name="Course_Each">
                <value><![CDATA[$ 15.00]]></value>
            </column>
        </<record>
   </<records>
</response>
```

Any suggestions on how to configure js2xmlparser to do this? Or is there another node.js utility that can help with this transformation task? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by writing my own custom function:

```
    const json2XML = async (jsonFilePathName) => {
        const jsonObj = await loadDataObj(jsonFilePathName)
        let xmlRecords = '';
        let xmlRecordBegin = '';
        let xmlRecordFull;
        jsonObj.forEach((newRecord) => {
            const fieldNames = Object.keys(newRecord);
            let colElements = '';
            let colElement;
            let colValue;
            xmlRecordBegin = `<record id="${newRecord.ID}">`;
            fieldNames.forEach((fieldName) => {
                //iterate through all fieldNames except ID
                if (fieldName !== 'ID') {
                    colValue = newRecord[fieldName];
                    colElement = `<column name="${fieldName}"><value><![CDATA[${colValue}]]></value></column>`;
                    colElements = colElements + colElement;
                }
            });
            //end fieldNames.forEach((fieldName)
            xmlRecordFull = xmlRecordBegin + colElements + '</record>';
            //console.log('xmlRecordFull = ', xmlRecordFull);
            xmlRecords = xmlRecords + xmlRecordFull;
        });
        //end jsonObj.forEach((newRecord)
        xmlDoc = xmlDecl + xmlRootBegin + xmlRecordsBegin + xmlRecords + xmlRecordsEnd + xmlRootEnd;
        return xmlDoc;
    }
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but XML is more than just a string.  Your code will work, however it'll break (create invalid XML), if one of your variables contains a special XML character (like <,>,&,").  You might consider the xmlbuilder node package, that won't have this vulnerability.  Also, you don't have to wrap element values in CDATA.  CDATA is rarely used, typically in cases were you want to embed an entire document in an element.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! I'll check out xmlbuilder. Yes, I know it's brittle - no error or data checking. I needed something fast to EXACTLY recreate a legacy XML data file from current json data. So far it's working fine, as a proof-of-concept, but I won't put it into a mission-critical app. Thanks again for your feedback.

Comment: Yes, sometimes you do what you gotta do.  Good luck w/your project.